# Functions in class in other files (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a problem in my python code. I want to execute functions that are in classes in a file called (functions.py). If I run the main file (main.py), the functions will not work.

**Project root:**

```
         .________ main.py
project  |
         |________ functions.py
```

**main.py**

```py
import functions
import time

print("Hello World")
time.sleep(1)
functions.clear()
```

**functions.py**

```py
import time
import os
import sys
import math

class color:
  PURPLE = "\033[95ml"
  BLACK = "\033[30m"
  CYAN = "\033[96m"
  DARKCYAN = "\033[36m"
  BLUE = "\033[94m"
  GREEN = "\033[92m"
  YELLOW = "\033[93m"
  RED = "\033[91m"
  BOLD = "\033[1m"
  UNDERLINED = "\033[4m"
  MAGENTA = "\033[35m"
  GREY = "\033[90m"
  ITALIC = "\033[3m"
  END = "\033[0m"

class functions:
  def clear():
    if os.name == "nt":
      os.system("cls")
 
    else:
      os.system("clear")
  
  def animation(text):
    for letter in text:
      time.sleep(0.01)
      sys.stdout.write(letter)
      sys.stdout.flush()

class mathematics:
  def add(a, b):
    print(a + b)
  
  def subtract(a, b):
    print(a - b)
  
  def multiply(a, b):
    print(a * b)
  
  def divide(a, b):
    print(a / b)

class colors:
  def red_text(text):
    print(f"{color.RED}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def blue_text(text):
    print(f"{color.BLUE}{text}{color.END}")

  def yellow_text(text):
    print(f"{color.YELLOW}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def purple_text(text):
    print(f"{color.PURPLE}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def cyan_text(text):
    print(f"{color.CYAN}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def darkcyan_text(text):
    print(f"{color.DARKCYAN}{text}{color.END}")

  def green_text(text):
    print(f"{color.GREEN}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def black_text(text):
    print(f"{color.BLACK}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def magenta_text(text):
    print(f"{color.MAGENTA}{text}{color.END}")

class markdown:
  def bold_text(text):
    print(f"{color.BOLD}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def underlined_text(text):
    print(f"{color.UNDERLINED}{text}{color.END}")
  
  def italic_text(text):
    print(f"{color.ITALIC}{text}{color.END}")

  def highlight_text(text):
    print(f"{color.HIGHLIGHT}{text}{color.END}")

def ready():
  functions.animation(f"{color.RED}You are using the Print-functions library by W1L7{color.END}")
  time.sleep(1)
  functions.clear()

ready()
```

If I run the code, it print this:

[image]

I don't know how to fix my error. Please be kind. I'm not advanced in python.

Comment: You need to create an instance to `functions`, not call `functions.clear` directly.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: In your own words, where you have `class functions:` in your code, why have you written this, and what do you think it does?

Comment: The problem is you are defining a class functions inside the module functions but only calling the module. Do functions.functions.clear()

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, i don't understand very well

Comment: Then you should try to follow a tutorial and learn the fundamentals, and not write code that you don't understand. You should have a reason for every line of code that you write, that you can clearly explain to another person.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia it worked. Also, il will rename my file. Thanks (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@samarthbhatia put the simpler solution in comments. I rename the functions.py file to wprint.py

In the main.py file, I need to put `wprint.functions.clear()` instead of `functions.clear`. Thanks samart!

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to include the word `self` in every function in the class. Also, you need to put it as the **first** parameter of the function:

```
def clear(self):
```

Quoting from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/#:%7E:text=self%20represents%20the%20instance%20of,to%20refer%20to%20instance%20attributes.)

> `self` represents the instance of the class. By using the`self` keyword we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python. It binds the attributes with the given arguments.
> The reason you need to use self. is because Python does not use the @ syntax to refer to instance attributes

So all your function definitions **inside** the class will have a `self` parameter as the **first** one

```
class functions:
  def clear(self):
    ....
  
  def animation(self,text):
    ...

class mathematics:
  def add(self,a, b):
    ...
  
  def subtract(self,a, b):
    ...
  
  def multiply(self,a, b):
    ...
  
  def divide(self,a, b):
    ...

class colors:
  def red_text(self,text):
    ...
  
  def blue_text(self,text):
    ...

  def yellow_text(text):
    ...

  def purple_text(self,text):
    ...
  
  def cyan_text(self,text):
    ...
  
  def darkcyan_text(self,text):
    ...

  def green_text(self,text):
    ...
  
  def black_text(self,text):
    ...
  
  def magenta_text(self,text):
    ...

class markdown:
  def bold_text(self,text):
    ...
  
  def underlined_text(self,text):
    ....
  
  def italic_text(self,text):
    ...

  def highlight_text(self,text):
    ...

def ready():
  functions.animation(f"{color.RED}You are using the Print-functions library by W1L7{color.END}")
  time.sleep(1)
  functions.clear()

ready()
```

Comment: Thx, but do I need a __init__() function? And do I need to add self in the function who is in the  main file?

Comment: @W1L74680. I don't think you need an ```__init__``` function. And yes, you need to create an instance of the class to access the different function. Now, you want to access ```clear()```. So you would do ```from functions import functions``` then ```functions.clear()``` where ```functions``` is the class and ```clear()``` is the function

Comment: What I was meaning, it's do you write functions in main.py like this: ```functions.clear(self)``` or like that ```functions.clear()```

Comment: @W1L74680. The second one. The ```self``` parameter can help us access the attributes. Not need to pass ```self``` as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

#### You have 2 issues in your code:

1. Don't use python file and class name same, it will confuse you.
2. As @Sujay said, you forgot a `self` in `functions` method `clear`

#### sample code:

```
main.py

import foo
x = foo.functions()
x.clear()

foo.py

class functions:
    def clear(self):
        print("functions clear")
```

#### result:

```
functions clear
```